# PyQt5 macOS usage

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, pyqt5

I installed PyQt5 using `brew install pyqt5` which worked. I am using Python 3.7.1 which was also installed using `brew`.

When I execute a Python script where i used `from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt` I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 15, in <module>
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'
```

Is there something else I need to to so I can use PyQt in Python?

Comment: My guess is that Homebrew pyqt doesn't pull qt by default you have to install it separately

Comment: @geckos I checked and homebrew pulls qt as a dependency for pyqt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get this to work when trying to install `pyqt5` using `homebrew`. Instead, I just used `pip` to install it with the following command `pip3 install pyqt5`.